# Can't Get Google Client API simple.php example to work

Tags: php, google-client

Just trying to use the Google Client API to pull traffic data for my site and thought I would try the simple.php file on https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/contacts/simple.php

I've edited it appropriately for my credentials and I can get it to go from the "Connect Me" link to the request permission page, but after I accept I end up at "This webpage is not available". I'm wondering if there might be an issue with needing the token refreshed?

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<?php
require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Analytics PHP Starter Application");

// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=analytics to generate your
// client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
$client->setClientId('MY_CLIENT_ID');
$client->setClientSecret('MY_CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setDeveloperKey('MY_DEVELOPER_KEY');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/google-analytics/simple.php');
$service = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $props = $service->management_webproperties->listManagementWebproperties("~all");
  print "<h1>Web Properties</h1><pre>" . print_r($props, true) . "</pre>";

  $accounts = $service->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
  print "<h1>Accounts</h1><pre>" . print_r($accounts, true) . "</pre>";
  $segments = $service->management_segments->listManagementSegments();
  print "<h1>Segments</h1><pre>" . print_r($segments, true) . "</pre>";
  $goals = $service->management_goals->listManagementGoals("~all", "~all", "~all");
  print "<h1>Segments</h1><pre>" . print_r($goals, true) . "</pre>";
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}
```